# How to pass parameter only to middleware that need it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have an Express application and I'm trying to put all my middleware in its own file. Some of the middleware functions need the `db` object and some don't.

It's pretty straightforward for the functions that don't need the `db` object, but given my code structure below, how can I reference the `db` object in `doesNotNeedDbParam` since it already has params `req`, `res`, and `next`?

somefile.js:

```
const router = express.Router()
const doesNotNeedDbParam = require('./middleware')().doesNotNeedDbParam

function foo () {
  // Currently I have to call require and pass in the db object here b/c 
  // it's not set when requiring the function doesNotNeedDbParam
  router.use(require('./middleware')(db).needsDbParam // <-- Is there a better way to do this so that I can require the file above and pass the db object in when it's set?
}

// Setup db object here
foo()
```

middleware.js

```
function doesNotNeedDbParam (req, res, next) {
  ...
}

function needsDbParam (req, res, next) {
  // Where do I reference the db variable?
}

module.exports = (db) => {
  return {
    doesNotNeedDbParam: doesNotNeedDbParam,
    needsDbParam: needsDbParam
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Functional Approach

I think a good structure for this is to try [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) your middleware. This is a pattern practiced by middleware such as [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and internally by Express itself with [`serve-static`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static). This way, you only have to require once, and pass `db` where you need to, and don't where you don't need it:

```
// Instead of declaring each function directly as a middleware function,
// we declare them as a function that returns a middleware function
function doesNotNeedDbParam () {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    …
  }
}

function needsDbParam (db) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    // You can use db here along with req, res, next
  }
}

// No need to export a function now
module.exports = {
  doesNotNeedDbParam,
  needDbParam,
};
```

Then, just require:

```
const middleware = require('./middleware');
…
router.use(middleware.doesNotNeedDbParam()); // Since this doesn't need anything, no argument
router.use(middleware.needsDbParam(db)); // You can pass db here now
```

If you're comfortable with ES6+ syntax, you can condense to:

```
const doesNotNeedDbParam = () => (req, res, next) => {
  …
}

const needsDbParam = (db) => (req, res, next) => {
  // Use db here
}
// Export object here...
```

Then:

```
const { doesNotNeedDbParam, needsDbParam } = require('./middleware');
… 
router.use(doesNotNeedDbParam());
router.use(needsDbParam(db));
```

---

### Attach Approach

There's also another way you can do this, by attaching a property to the `req` object *once*. This removes the need to repass `db` every single time you want it. Many other packages use this strategy. It goes something like this:

```
function attachDb (db) { // Still use curry approach here since we want db
  return function (req, res, next) {
    // Attaches the specified db to req directly
    req.db = db;
  }
}

function needsDbParam (req, res, next) { // No need for currying
  // Now use req.db here
}
// Export your other middleware…
```

Then, use it like so, make sure `attachDb` is *first* so that the property is assigned before you use it:

```
router.use(attachDb(db)); // Before all other middleware that depend on req.db
…
// No need to call because this is already the middleware function, 
// able to use req.db, which was assigned via attachDb
router.use(needDbParam);
```

Comment: @Catfish This answer actually makes more sense since it scopes `db` to only the function that requires it. Keep in mind that `db` will still need to be initialized prior to `require`.

Comment: @NorianNyx Not necessarily. `db` is only needed when calling curried middleware function. You can require at the top of the file and pass `db` later. I also added another approach I see often, attaching a property to the `req` object that can be used later down the pipeline.

Comment: I apologize, what I meant was it needed to be initialized before `router.use`, not `require`.

Comment: This is a great response. Answers the question, makes references to accepted patterns used in the Express community and teaches a bit about classic functional patterns like currying. Nice!

Answer (score -1):

Why not just declare `module.exports` as a single function:

```js
module.exports = (db) => { 
    let module = {}; 

    module.doesNotNeedDbParam = (req, res) => {
        // Do Stuff
    };

    module.needsDbParam = (req, res) => { 
        // db now in scope
    };

    return module;
};
```

This is what your `somefile.js` would become:

```js
const router = express.Router();
const db = initializeDb();

const doesNotNeedDbParam = require('./middleware')().doesNotNeedDbParam;
router.use(require('./middleware')(db).needsDbParam);
```

You could also set it up once like this:

```
const middleware = require('./middleware')(db);
const doesNotNeedParam = middleware.doesNotNeedParam;
router.use(middleware.needsDbParam);
```

This isn't really any different than what you were doing before, but now you have access to db inside of `needsDbParam`. If your `initializeDb` function is async, then you will need to use `Promise` or some other async library to include after the db is set up.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how i'd call this given my somefile.js example above? I don't think the db object would have been initialized but maybe i'm thinking about it wrongly

Comment: You're right that `db` will need to be initialized before passing it into the module, but at least it will look consistent. I will post code of what it will look like.

Comment: @Catfish Did you figure this out, or are you still having trouble?